# "props should be defined" but how?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux, expo

I am new to react and react native.

I am trying to set up a simple app, using this tutorial

https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/MINI_TUTORIAL.md

I have set up my app with this command

```
create-react-native-app my-project
```

I start the app and see it in expo on my phone.

Then

```
npm i react-native-router-flux --save
```

I replace the contents of `App.js` with all the code from that tutorial. I also create the required `PageOne.js` and `PageTwo.js`.

I then get an immediate error on my phone.

> [react-native-router-flux] props should be defined
>
> assert
>   c:\my path...\react-native-router-flux\src\Util.js@34:10

How do I define these props? What do I need to do to get this working?

Extras!

The code is exactly as in that tutorial,

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Router, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux';

import PageOne from './PageOne';
import PageTwo from './PageTwo';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Scene key="root">
          <Scene key="pageOne" component={PageOne} title="PageOne" initial={true} />
          <Scene key="pageTwo" component={PageTwo} title="PageTwo" />
        </Scene>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

PageOne.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

export default class PageOne extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{margin: 128}}>
        <Text onPress={Actions.pageTwo}>This is PageOne! </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

PageTwo.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

export default class PageTwo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{margin: 128}}>
        <Text onPress={Actions.pageOne}>This is PageTwo!</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code of your root index.

Comment: I have done this

Comment: one thing if I do `npm outdated` I see the current version of react is 16.0.0-alpha.12 and the wanted is the same, but the latest is 15.6.1. I have not specified I want an alpha build. Is this some Expo weirdness forcing me to use an Alpha causing issues?

Comment: What's the version of react native?

Comment: react-native: 0.44.0

Comment: Now having upgraded a load of things I get this `Error: You are using npm version 5.0.3. Please use an npm version that is >= 3.0.0 and < 5.0.0.` what a mess!

Comment: I downgraded npm to the last stable 4 version using this guide `npm install -g npm@4.6.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really have a conclusive answer. Perhaps just being new to a lot of different moving parts had caused something to get out of line.

I updated some magic numbers in `package.json` and `app.json` according to the upgrade table on this page

https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/VERSIONS.md

and things started to work again.

I suppose that some of my thrashing around installing various react things had gotten the installed versions out of step. Perhaps if I really understood the ecosystem it would seem clear to me but it feels like a bunch of string and bailing wire at the moment!